# how to read/write a raw jpeg MCU block from an image ? [.net preffered] [maybe using a 3rd party iamge library]

Tags: c#, image, jpeg, minimum-coded-unit

i want to read the raw image data of a jpeg so i can manipulate it without loosing any quality when doing so.
i took a look at the LibJpeg.Net library http://bitmiracle.com/libjpeg .
but there is a lot of code and couldnt find anything about reading/writing raw blocks.
mainly i want to implement lossless editing of a jpeg image and was wondering how to do it?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg#Lossless_editing
thanks

### Update:

basically what i want to do is to access the jpeg block data as some kind of array so i can read the data.
and then i want to create a new jpeg and access some kind of block data array that i can fill with rows from other images.
the tasks seems easy but the problem is that the documentation of libJpeg.net is not that clear.
i have reached this state of code now.

```
var cinfo = new BitMiracle.LibJpeg.Classic.jpeg_decompress_struct();
cinfo.jpeg_stdio_src(new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\File.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Open));
cinfo.jpeg_read_header(true);
cinfo.jpeg_start_decompress();
```

but that is it , i dont know where to find that array of MCU blocks or if i am even reading the right structure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470107/extracting-dct-coefficients-from-encoded-images-and-video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe BitMiracle.LibJpeg.Classic.jpeg_decompress_struct.jpeg_read_raw_data() will do what you need.

You may also want to review JpegCodec implementation in [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/). That codec uses LibJpeg.Net for various purposes. Reading of uncompressed jpeg data is among of them.

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of the library.

Comment: i tried to add the code |byte[][][] arr = new byte[16][][];| cinfo.jpeg_read_raw_data(arr, 16); | but it gives me the error "Improper call to JPEG library in state 205"

Comment: i will try to trace into the source code to see why this is happening, also i wanted to ask you if u know where can i find documentation on function in libJpeg.NET for example "jpeg_read_raw_data()" because the documentation in "LibJpeg.NET documentation.chm" is nice in the tutorials but the functions themself are not documented , so i cant know what does jpeg_read_raw_data() do for example or what kind of parameters it excepts , other then that excelent work :)

Comment: unfortunately, documentation for LibJpeg.Net is not complete yet. we've prepared only some tutorials to help those who migrate from original libjpeg library.
documentation for functions/methods is expected to be found in documentation for original libjpeg library for now.

Comment: maybe "Raw (downsampled) image data" chapter in original libjpeg distribution will help you to properly setup decompression structure before reading raw data.

Comment: i turned out that i needed to get the DCT coefficients for what i needed to do (merge several jpegs in a loseless way) using jpeg_read_coefficients(). but thanks for guiding me to the right way.the problem i am having right now that i try to allocate a block array and i got out of memory when i try to alocate  a large number using this code BitMiracle.LibJpeg.Classic.jpeg_common_struct.CreateBlocksArray(32 * 177, 32 * 101); . i dont think this is a lot data. i have 3.5GB of ram on windows XP 32bits. thanks

Comment: Karim, I think it would be better for all to continue this discussion by e-mail. Please write us (support@bitmiracle.com) and we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that jpeglib has public functions for that. They support lossless transformations in the jtransform_execute_transformation, but only have rotate90/280/2780, flip, crop, and transpose.

You'll have to read the source of that function to find out how it gets the blocks.  A quick look shows it using

```
srcinfo->mem->access_virt_barray
```

Which is a ptr-to-function, where `srcinfo` is a `j_decompress_ptr`.  It gets a `JBLOCKARRAY` from that.

I would try to read `do_flip_v` which should be an easy transformation to understand.

Comment: i dont understand to which version of jpeglib you refer? because i am looking @ Libjpeg.net which dont have such line of code (also the line of code is C and not c#)

Comment: I don't know libjpeg.net -- so hopefully there's something similar to look for.  I am looking at libjpeg (the C version).  You can wrap it in .NET if you want to.

Comment: Check to see if they implement the lossless flip transformation. If so, read the code for that -- should be fairly easy to understand -- it just reads each block, flips it and moves it.

Comment: well thanks. i will try to look into the code but the code is undocumented and so its not very easy to read. the good news is that source code is available :)