# libjpeg jpeg_write_coefficients

Tags: c++, image-processing, libjpeg

I have created my own DCT calculation.

How do I use `jpeg_write_coefficients` to write my 64 DCT values into JPEG file using `jpeg_write_coefficients` (it needs `jvirt_barray_ptr * coef_arrays`)?

How do I create this?

Comment: did this ever get solved there is literally not a single example on the internet of how to make one of these array structures from raw data as opposed to just using the one we got from "read coeff" function ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look around for the `request_virt_barray` function (in `jmemmgr.c`).

Also have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470107/extracting-dct-coefficients-from-encoded-images-and-video).  It's reading DCT coefficients as opposed to writing them, but it should give you an idea of how coefficient arrays are stored like.  Aside from the coefficients, you also need to pass in the quantization table (through the `j_compress_ptr cinfo` struct).  This is because inside the libjpeg library, forward DCT and quantization is performed in one step.  If you want to do the forward DCT by yourself, you have to do the quantization yourself too.

It's also worth reading through the libjpeg documentation.  It's long, but actually quite readable, and will greatly improve your understanding of the library.  The most helpful file is `structure.txt`.  It has sections on memory management and the encoder structure that are likely to help you.

Comment: Do I need to perform these methods in sequence request -> alloc -> realize by myself?

Answer (score 0):

you need coefficient array as input to write your files as variable type `jvirt_barray_ptr` . you may fill it by reading it from an image and

> jvirt_barray_ptr *coeffs_array = jpeg_read_coefficients(&cinfo);

or fill it by yourself. Then you have to write your dct input data like this. In the following function I used `jpeg_decompress_struct` as input to use my first image header to the output image header

```
int write_jpeg_file_dct(std::string outname,jpeg_decompress_struct in_cinfo, jvirt_barray_ptr *coeffs_array ){

    struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
    FILE * infile;

    if ((infile = fopen(outname.c_str(), "wb")) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", outname.c_str());
      return 0;
    }

    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
    jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);
    jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, infile);

    j_compress_ptr cinfo_ptr = &cinfo;
    jpeg_copy_critical_parameters((j_decompress_ptr)&in_cinfo,cinfo_ptr);
    jpeg_write_coefficients(cinfo_ptr, coeffs_array);

    jpeg_finish_compress( &cinfo );
    jpeg_destroy_compress( &cinfo );
    fclose( infile );

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow `jpeg_read_coefficients` to create structure of dct coefficient manager，such as

> :dstInfo->mem->alloc_small,dstInfo->mem->request_virt_barray,dstInfo->mem->realize_virt_arrays

And use `virt_barray_list` to get dst target to put new dct coefficient/quantyTableQ into it. Then you call jpeg_write_coefficients to generate JPEG file.