# Extract Dct coefficient from images python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, transform, dct

I have seen the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497493/2527680) describing how DCT coefficients can be extracted and visualized in C++.

I have seen the [python API](https://pythonhosted.org/bob.ip.base/py_api.html).
Where there is a function `bob.ip.base.DCTFeatures()`.

```
bob.ip.base.DCTFeatures (coefficients, block_size, [block_overlap], [normalize_block], [normalize_dct], [square_pattern])
```

How to I initialize there parameters ? Can This be done directly depending of the input image given?

And how do I visualize them as in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470107/extracting-dct-coefficients-from-encoded-images-and-video/4497493#4497493). But in python.

for example

[image: This lena image]

To Transform into

DC images (64x64): luma Cr Cb RGB

[image][image][image][image]